# Should we migrate all 'Jiddu Krishnamurti' questions to Philosophy.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, vote-to-close, migration

Questions like: [What are the teachings of Sri Jiddu Krishnamurti?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17780)

[This](http://www.jkrishnamurti.org/content/there-truth-religions) is what he thought about all religions:

> The question is: **Is there not truth in religions, in theories, in ideals, in beliefs?**
>
> Let us examine. What do we mean by religion? Surely, not organized religion, not Hinduism, Buddhism, or Christianity—which are all organized beliefs with their propaganda, conversion, proselytism, compulsion, and so on. Is there any truth in organized religion? It may engulf, enmesh truth, but the organized religion itself is not true. **Therefore, organized religion is false, it separates man from man**. You are a Muslim, I am a Hindu, another is a Christian or a Buddhist—and we are wrangling, butchering each other. Is there any truth in that? We are not discussing religion as the pursuit of truth, but we are considering if there is any truth in organized religion. We are so conditioned by organized religion to think there is truth in it that we have come to believe that by calling oneself a Hindu, one is somebody, or one will find God. How absurd, sir; to find God, to find reality, there must be virtue. Virtue is freedom, and only through freedom can truth be discovered—not when you are caught in the hands of organized religion, with its beliefs. And is there any truth in theories, in ideals, in beliefs? Why do you have beliefs? Obviously, because beliefs give you security, comfort, safety, a guide. In yourself you are frightened, you want to be protected, you want to lean on somebody, and therefore you create the ideal, which prevents you from understanding that which is. Therefore, an ideal becomes a hindrance to action.

Voting to close the question [did not help](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/close/21206). And I'm pretty sure those who voted to keep it open believe in organized religion :)

Also, what do we do with answers citing his works?

Answer (score -1):

**No, we need not**.

Jiddu Krishnamurthy was born into a Telugu household in Madras presidency and should generally be considered a Hindu philosopher with liberal views.
Hinduism is a kind of umbrella term for several sects & sub religions, which are non Abrahmic. So Him not subscribing to the organised religion is also clarified in the following excerpt:

> I maintain that truth is a pathless land, and **you cannot approach it by any path whatsoever, by any religion, by any sect**. That is my point of view, and I adhere to that absolutely and unconditionally. Truth, being limitless, unconditioned, unapproachable by any path whatsoever, **cannot be organized; nor should any organization be formed to lead or coerce people** along a particular path.  [[source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiddu_Krishnamurti#Break_with_the_past)

Not believing in organised religion is also part of broader interpretation of Hinduism. As [stated by supreme court](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27212/1049):

5. Recognition of the fact that the means or ways to salvation are many.
6. ...
7. Unlike other religions or religious creeds **Hindu religion not being tied-down to any definite set of philosophic concepts**, as such.

Personally IMO, Jiddu Krishnamurthy related discussion is not "off-topic" to migrate to other sites and will be a good asset for this site.

Comment: 'should generally be considered a Hindu philosopher' - even when he himself clarified he doesn't subscribe to Hinduism or Hindu ideas? Can one also ask for views/teachings of Confucius (or start quoting him in answers) if someone establishes a connection between him and India/Hinduism? Now if Jiddu Krishnamurti has written about Hinduism, I guess one can cite him in answers. Also, imagine someone asking 'What are iammilind's views/teachings?' - on what basis is the question valid or invalid?

Comment: Jiddu Krishnamurti was born in HIndu household but his views were close like Taoist like Osho. If he chose to follow other religion, that is not following definite set of philosophical concept but other religion completely. He didn't subscribe to any religion but a philosopher. It is same like allowing Confucius or Aristotile questions.

Comment: @sv., Sarvabhouma -- whether to include [or not], the works of Jiddu Krishnamurthy's, also depends on what we refer as "Hinduism". I personally adhere to supreme court's decision in this case, as it seems sensible as well as inline with philosophy of *"SanAtana Dharma"*. The identity of "Hindu" is relatively modern term. It was common for many philosophers to derive their thought process from other religions. e.g. Vivekananda had good influence from Buddhism, Osho had spoken on many religions; but his commentary on Gita was the top among his works, though he was Jain. Just an opinion.